# Receiving HTTP data in Yii2 action from an Unknown URL

Tags: php, yii2

I have been trying to receive data send to my Yii2 action for a while now but to no success. I have tried lots of different algorithms and ideas. I am working on receiving data sent to me by Orange API for base on clients payment status. 
from Instructions on their website, they say, once the status has been confirmed, ..... HTTP notification is posted to the notif_url( my notification URL which I provided to them say https://www.example2.org/notif  ). 
They futher provide the format for the data as:

POST http://www.example2.org/notif
{
   "status":"SUCCESS",
   "notif_token":"dd497bda3b250e536186fc0663f32f40",
   "txnid": "MP150709.1341.A00073"
}

I have written my Yii2 Action as shown below

```
public function actionNotif(){
    $request = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $transaction = OrangeFeedback::findOne(['notif_token'=>$request->notif_token]);
    $transaction->status = $request->status;
    $transaction->txnid =  $request->txnid;
    $transaction->save();
    if($request->status == 'SUCCESS'){
        //Do some processing
```

But this code doesn't work. I do not understand what I am missing in receiving this request. Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey post returns array not object.... use $request['notif_token'];

Comment: tried that but it doesnt work

Comment: It seems as if my action is not been executed. This is because, I have set default values and I actually get to receive the data in the DB. But when I get a successful transaction on their web application which is suppose to call call my action and pass the data, I do not recive anything.  might be i am missing some configurations or something

Comment: Try this $params = \Yii::$app->request->bodyParams; $params['notif_token'];

Comment: Thanks Govind. I had tried that already and I have tried it again but it does not work. I just believe the action does not execute at all. But when I look at my config and behaviors, everything is default and I do not see anything that can prevent this action from been executed. From the Orange end, they say, my request was properly handled and feedback successfully send so it is at my level to receive it that I have issues

Comment: This might be because of the [CSRF validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-best-practices#avoiding-csrf)

Comment: Hello Bizley, thanks for that help. Yeah CRSF was blocking my action from executing. Now I can get an effect when I try to get this data. But I am still unable to get this data send using the method above . Please any idea will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have even tried getting it as raw php with &_POST['notif_token] but I do not succeed

Comment: If `$_POST['notif_token']` is not available problem might be somewhere else. You need to make sure you are receiving the data at all.

Comment: public function actionOnotification(){      
       OrangeFeedback::findOne(['notif_token'=>$_POST['notif_token']]);
        $transaction->status = 1; Bizley, that is my code. I do not understand why it is not working. I still think the data doesnt enter the action. CSRF disabled allows the action to be executed but what allows data to be posted because I don't seem to understand 
        $transaction->txnid =  1;
        $transaction->save();
        if($request['status'] == 'SUCCESS'){
       //do somthing.

Comment: I just tried using GET, POST and $request->bodyParams just to discover that each of them is return an empty array to my action. Please any ideas